# How to create a pin cushion (or barrel) distortion from the square function on Cartesian coordinate?

Tags: numerics, coordinate-transformation

I want to make a distorted square shape in 2D data set from a rectangular function.

[image]

Here is my code to draw a square shape(Field length : 10, Square length: 5, Data num : 101).

```
x1 = ArrayReshape[Transpose[Tuples[Range[-(10/2), 10/2, .1], 2]][[1]], {101, 101}];
y1 = ArrayReshape[Transpose[Tuples[Range[-(10/2), 10/2, .1], 2]][[2]], {101, 101}];
rect[A_] := (UnitStep[x1 + A/2] - UnitStep[x1 - A/2]) (UnitStep[y1 + A/2] - UnitStep[y1 - A/2]);
ArrayPlot[rect[5], ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `ImageTransformation`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example how to distort images (cushion or barrel):

```
grid = Table[{i, j}, {i, -10, 10}, {j, -10, 10}];
grid = Join[grid, Transpose[grid]];
distor[p_, dis_] := p/(1 - dis Norm[p]^2);
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Line /@ Map[distor[#, dis] &, grid, {2}]]
 , {{dis, 0}, -.003, .003}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]